# How to recovered destroyed partition(dd command)

Tags: command-line, partitioning, data-recovery, dd

So I have been using a ubuntu livecd to help backup my windows os that won't start. I used the sudo dd if=dev/sda4 of dev/sdc1 accidentally and OVERWROTE the whole 700gig external hard drive and it now only shows up as an 11 gig drive with 3 gig remaining? The 11 gig was a small partition from my computers hard drive, but it somehow replaced the whole 700gig external HD that had tons of family photos and valueable stuff(400gig worth).

I am using testdisk now to scan for lost partitions. Also the drive now shows the 690 gigs as "unallocated". How can I recover the data?

Comment: Was it one large partition? It only overwrote the first 11GB, but that would also have changed partition. You may be able to recover old partition with testdisk, but may need photorec to recover the data if testdisk does not show it.

Comment: Yes it was one large partition

Comment: bump.... I still need help. Test disk shows one result cbut says check_fat, cant read boot sector D fat16 lba

Comment: Boot-Sector was part of what you overwrote. If deep seach in testdisk does not show files then you are into tools that scan drive. Photorec will work but slow, you need another drive with 400GB of space to copy data to and it does not recover file names, just extensions. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step  If partition was NTFS, some say Windows tools may work better, but those that do also charge.